# Saving metadata into Node (from Neo4j) using java

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using neo4j through java and I was wondering if there's a way to save some metadata with that node. I wanted to be able to have a node from the graph include more information, for instance to have each node have a dictionary associated with it.

edit - A dictionary was just an example, I want to be able to associate also class instances which contain as one of the fields a dictionary for example.

Comment: a dictionary is just a set of properties, right? So what's missing? Please explain your demand in more detail.

Comment: A dictionary was just an example, a bad one I guess, say I wanted to have a class instance as metadata. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in Neo4j.
Neo4j is simple property graph.
But you can "emulate" such behaviour by using conventions in your application.

### Special properties

You can specify in your application that all properties that starts with `__` are metadata.

Then storing metadata is trivial:

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    Node node = db.createNode();
    node.setProperty("__version", "1.0.0");
    node.setProperty("__author", "Dmitry");
    tx.success();
}
```

### JSON metadata

Other way - store JSON string in `__metadata` property and specify all your metadata as JSON.

Example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

// create node and set metadata
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.put("version", "1.0.0");
    metadata.put("author", "Dmitry");

    Node node = db.createNode();
    node.setProperty("__metadata", mapper.writeValueAsString(metadata));

    tx.success();
}

// find node and get metadata
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    Node node = db.findNode(...);

    Map<String, Object> metadata = map = mapper.readValue(
        node.getProperty("__metadata"), HashMap.class);

    tx.success();
}
```

**Note:** if you go with this option, then you should create some sort of wrapper/helper for `Node` to minimize code duplication.
**Note2:** `ObjectMapper` should be created only once per application.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this line:  "Map<String, Object> metadata = map = mapper.readValue(
        node.getProperty("__metadata"), HashMap.class);"                                   why do we need to use the mapper? Seems to me like you just need to convert the string back to a dictionary. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Danny yeap. We are using mapper to conver JSON string back to `Map`. Data are stored in Neo4j as string. We need to use mapper to serialize and deserialize data.

Comment: But why don't you use mapper to serialize the data. What I don't understand is why you need to use mapper to deserialize, but not to serialize.

Comment: I am using mapper for serialization. This line: `node.setProperty("__metadata", mapper.writeValueAsString(metadata));`. It serializes `Map` as string and set to `__metadata` node property.

Comment: How about having a class as metadata? I edited my question, sorry for the hassel.

Comment: Jackson is capable to serialize/deserialize classes too. You can checkout readme/tutorials. It is simple, but powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer you can easily create a separate node representing your class and holding class-level meta information.

Either connect all the nodes representing instances to the class node using a relationship (this might cause lock contention if a lot of instances are added concurrently) or use a naming convention:

- Node for instances: `(:Person{name:'Danny'})`
- Metanode for person: `(:Meta{clazz:'Person', metaProp1: value1, ...})`

So the label if the instance node is linked to the clazz property of the meta node.